# PDFTron HTML to PDF conversion fail and error code 0

Tags: java, pdftron

Below is the code we are using to convert html to pdf. It is working fine on windows environment but same code is not working on linux environment. Also I have check tempPath directory has read/Write access. "Conversion failed. HTTP Code: 0" converter.getLog() is empty

To set temp path for pdftron below is the lines

```
PDFNet.setTempPath(tempPath);
utils.PdfViewerLicense.initialize();
```

Code to convert Html to pdf

```
public static byte[]  generatePDF(String pdfHtml) throws PDFNetException {
  PDFDoc doc = null;
  HTML2PDF converter = null;
  byte [] bytes = null;
  try {
      converter = new HTML2PDF();
      doc = new PDFDoc();
      converter.setLandscape(false);
      converter.insertFromHtmlString(pdfHtml);
      if (converter.convert(doc)) {
          bytes = doc.save( SDFDoc.e_linearized, null);
      } else {
          throw new PDFNetException("", 1L, "", "", "Conversion failed. HTTP Code: " + converter.getHTTPErrorCode() + "\n" + converter.getLog());
      }
  } catch (PDFNetException e) {
      throw e;
  }catch(Exception ex){
      throw new PDFNetException("", 1L, "", "", ex.getMessage());
  }finally {
      if(converter!=null)
          converter.destroy();
      if(doc!=null)
          doc.close();
  }
  return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Does it get the file from the `tempPath` at all? Seems like for windows it is read correctly but Linux the path is not being read properly.

Comment: Which file? we are setting the path so that PDFTron can use that directory for processing.

Comment: Probably the path isn't a correct fit for Linux? could you post the sample path which you are passing? How does it look like?

Comment: we are reading from CATALINA_HOME

Comment: Ok. then shouldn't you initialize PDFNet? Like calling `PDFNet.initialize();`. Because in our code we have never Initialized the license but PDFNet.

Comment: We have initialise license of pdftron. So that is not a case.

Comment: What distro are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the HTML2PDF.so file is executable for at least the user agent you are running under (maybe make executable for everyone). This should be described in the readme that comes with the html2pdf download.

Answer (score 0):

Adding executable permission on lib files present in HTML2PDF module worked for me

```
chmod a+x HTML2PDFMac/html2pdf_chromium.dylib 
chmod a+x HTML2PDFMac/libswiftshader_libGLESv2.dylib
chmod a+x HTML2PDFMac/libswiftshader_libEGL.dylib
```